# How to multiply a string by a variable integer in python

Tags: python, string, variables, printing, integer

I'm having trouble multiplying a string by a variable that is a integer. Integer is in as variable form because it is an input that is entered by the user. However I cannot get the them to multiply together so I can print them. The program complies and runs but encounters a syntax error when it encounters the code where they're multiplied together.

```
gapVal=(" ")

gapSp=int(input("Please enter a the amount of spaces between the stars"))
gapSp2=(gapSp)-2
gapSp3=(gapSp2)-2

print("*", gapSp, "*", gapSp2, "*", gapSp3, "*")
```

Comment: remove () , otherwise you are dealing with tuples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However I understand what are you doing, do you want the code like this?

```
gapVal = " "

gapSp=int(input("Please enter a the amount of spaces between the stars"))
gapSp2 = gapSp - 2
gapSp3 = gapSp2 - 2

print("*", gapSp * gapVal,
      "*", gapSp2 * gapVal,
      "*", gapSp3 * gapVal, "*")
```

Comment: Thank you, you've helped a lot.